# Numpy horizontal concat with failure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I want to concatenate two numpy arrays with the shape `(100,3) and (100,7)` to get a `(100,10)` matrix.

I've tried it using `hstack, concatenate` but only receives a `ValueError: all the int arrays must have same number of dimensions`

In a dummy example like the following it works ...

```
x=np.arange(30).reshape(10,3)
y=np.arange(20).reshape(10,2)
np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1)
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I've created the first two metrics's with sklearn's preprocessing module (RobustScaler and OneHotEncoder).

**UPDATE 2:**

When using scipy.sparse.hstack it works, but why

Comment: Can you update your question with more info about your original array?

Comment: Works with hstack: `np.hstack([x, y])`. Are you sure the shapes of `x` and `y` are compatible?

Comment: @kennytm, I have print(x.shape, y.shape) wich gives (100,3) (100,7) with an error message "all the input ... " - traceback  comes from stack return _nx.concatenate(arrs,1)

Comment: @Roby What is `_nx`? What is `arrs`? `np.concatenate((x, y), axis=1)` works for me too.

Comment: @kennytm thats the traceback from numpy/core/shape_base.py - when using spicy.sparse.hstack it works - but why ?

Comment: `_nx` is the name for `np` internal to these `np.stack` functions  The family of `np.stack` functions all use `np.concatenate`.

Comment: @Roby wait are they sparse array or normal arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sparse hstack joins the `coo` attributes and builds a new `coo` sparse matrix from those.  The numpy hstack knows nothing about the different sparse structure.  To explain this further I'd have to explain sparse construction, and quote from the respective functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate it vertically `axis` must beequal to 0. This is explained in [the doc for concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html).

In this link we have this example:

> > > a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
> > >
> > > b = np.array([[5, 6]])
> > >
> > > np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

> > > np.concatenate((a, b.T), axis=1)

```
array([[1, 2, 5],
       [3, 4, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine for me:

```
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(100 * 3).reshape(100,3)
y=np.arange(100 * 7).reshape(100,7)
np.hstack((x,y)).shape  # (100, 10)
```